# Okta AJAX Post Error - No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header

Tags: okta, okta-api

I am attempting to create a session token via the okta api.  I have enabled CORS via the okta documentation.

The "GET" below works:

```
function testGetApps() {
    var baseUrl = 'https://mydomain.okta.com';
    $.ajax({
        url: baseUrl + '/api/v1/users/userId/appLinks',
        type: 'GET',
        accept: 'application/json',
        headers: { Authorization : 'SSWS oktaApiKey'}
    }).done(function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    })
    .fail(function (xhr, textStatus, error) {
        var title, message;
        switch (xhr.status) {
            case 403:
                title = xhr.responseJSON.errorSummary;
                message = 'Please login to your Okta organization before running the test';
                break;
            default:
                title = 'Invalid URL or Cross-Origin Request Blocked';
                message = 'You must explictly add this site (' + window.location.origin + ') to the list of allowed websites in your Okta Admin Dashboard';
                break;
        }
        alert(title + ': ' + message);
    });
}
```

But the "POST" below fails with the error:

XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://mydomain.okta.com/api/v1/sessions?additionalFields=cookieToken. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://mydomain' is therefore not allowed access.

```
function initOktaSession() {
    var txtUserName = $('UserName').val();
    var txtPassword = $('Password').val();

    var data = { username: txtUserName, password: txtPassword };
    var requestUrl = 'https://mydomain.okta.com/api/v1/sessions?additionalFields=cookieToken';


    //Call Webservices to update
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: requestUrl,
        headers: {authorization : 'SSWS oktaApiKey'},
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        async: true,
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function (err) {
            console && console.log(err);
            !console && alert(err.status + ' ' + err.statusText);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Create Session](http://developer.okta.com/docs/api/rest/sessions.html#create-session) API call is not [CORS enabled](http://developer.okta.com/docs/getting_started/enabling_cors.html#api-support).

Comment: Apart from getting the error, how do you tell what is CORS enabled and what is not?

Comment: @ChrisDavis The documentation for the specific API indicates whether it is CORS enabled. For instance, the [get-user](http://developer.okta.com/docs/api/resources/users.html#get-user) call has an icon indicating it is CORS enabled.

Comment: I have added in my base url in trusted origin but still getting below error. https://<mycompany>.okta.com/oauth2/ausl2cu6foKJx4WXS0x7/v1/authorize?Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://example.com.com' is therefore not allowed access.  Can any one help me to overcome this.